# can I put a for loop inside a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

so for my code to work I need to be able to put a for loop in a for loop. For my project I'm trying to find all the words that begin with a letter in the alphabet. Ive not put how to store the data so please criticise me about that as I'm going to do that later. heres my code

```
wordfile = open('/usr/share/dict/words','r')
words = wordfile.read()
wordlist = words.split()
alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"

for word in wordlist:
    for letter in alphabet:
        if letter in alphabet == word[0] in wordlist:
            print(letter)
```

Comment: you want to print the first letter or the whole word? just print or you want the words for later?

Comment: First of all, Yes you can nest as many loops as you want,  secondly, you said *I'm trying to find all the words that begin with a letter in the alphabet.* : **Every word always begins with an alphabetical letter.**

Comment: @UbdusSamad i think he means token, in case that one token has date format or numeric

Comment: @Tzomas Hmm, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the words from a list that the first letter is in the alphabet:

```
wordfile = open('/usr/share/dict/words','r')
words = wordfile.read()
wordlist = words.split()
alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

alphabet_words = []
for word in wordlist:
    if word[0] in alphabet:
        alphabet_words.append(word)
```

Anyway you can use [comprehension lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that allow you to make simple loops inline, below the same code with this format:

```
wordfile = open('/usr/share/dict/words','r')
words = wordfile.read()
wordlist = words.split()
alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

alphabet_words = [word for word in wordlist if word[0] in alphabet]
```

Comment: +1 Looks good, you could also put a for loop based solution for him to understand it as list comprehensions could make no sense to OP.  Add a link say [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to your post as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, for example to find a string with only letters, no numbers, you can use [a-zA-Z]+

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

No looping ;-)